# Who came up with pooled mining?

Tags: mining-pools, history

What was the first implementation of pooled mining? Who came up with it?
What protocol did they use and where can it be found?

Answer (score 3):

Slush on December 16th 2010

http://mining.bitcoin.cz

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/History

Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: What about the entry at Sept 14th 2010: "Block 79,764 is first to be mined using split allocation of the generation reward." ?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull I don't really understand what it said in the Sept 14th entry. I understand it says something about the reward being generated from many places. I don't see the connection with pool mining